# Kivy MD: How to switch between different layouts using MD Tabs

Tags: python, layout, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to design a user interface in Python / Kivy MD. The layout should include a MDTab with some icons on top, a button at the bottom and some widgets in the middle. By clicking on the tab icons, the widget in the middle should change accordingly. For example modifying the text of a label (*see code*).
For this purpose, I'm trying to use a ScreenManager defined in the **Designer.kv** file. Anyway, I'm not sure is the most suitable object.

```
MDBoxLayout:
    screen_manager: screen_manager

    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10, 0, 10, 10
        
    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
        
        
    MDScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'screen1'
            MDBoxLayout:
                MDCheckbox:
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'TAB 1'        
        
        Screen:
            name: 'screen2'
            MDBoxLayout:
                MDCheckbox:
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'TAB 2'        
            
        
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'CONFIGURE'
        size_hint_x: 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y":0.5}
```

I recall the *screen_manager* object in the .py file using the *ObjectProperty*.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''
   

class MainApp(MDApp):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    icons = ["clock", "video-3d"]


    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('Designer.kv')
    
    
    def on_start(self):
        for tab_name in self.icons:
            self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(icon=tab_name))


    def on_tab_switch(
        self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        '''
        Called when switching tabs.

        :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
        :param instance_tab: <__main__.Tab object>;
        :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
        :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
        '''
        count_icon = instance_tab.icon
        
        if count_icon == self.icons[0]:
            self.screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
        elif count_icon == self.icons[1]:
            self.screen_manager.current = 'screen2'
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    MainApp().run()
```

When I run the code I get this error:
*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current'*.

How can I fix it? Any alternative ideas to switch between screen/layouts by clicking on Tab elements?

Comment: note, in my answer I changed from load_file to load_string.  This is only done for convenience as a one-item copy in this forum; it is not how I suggest things be done.  However, I do find it better to not try to return an object from the load_file method.  I think it is clearer to name the top level widget and define a Python class structure for it - as done in the answer.

Comment: ok so you don't suggest the use of the *load_string*? Do you prefer the *load_file method*? Why?

Comment: load_file is better for version control and to allow an IDE to help with auto complete and syntax highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several things to patch up - the code below should work.  screen_manager is not an object property, this is the MDScreenManager and it is given a type-hint to help your IDE indicate this.  The application has a top-level widget MyProject which inherits a box layout.  This Box Layout contains your tabs and the Screen Manager which, I think is the intention you have.

I added a function to your button and show two different levels where you could deploy it - within the top level widget or within the app.  I also moved creation of the tabs to be done sooner, when the top level widget is initialized.  The other code is commented away and it will also work; in case you choose to do it this way.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout

kv = Builder.load_string('''
<MyProject>:
    screen_manager: screen_manager
    _tabs: _tabs
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10, 0, 10, 10
        
    MDTabs:
        id: _tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
    MDScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'screen1'
            MDBoxLayout:
                MDCheckbox:
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'TAB 1'        
        
        Screen:
            name: 'screen2'
            MDBoxLayout:
                MDCheckbox:
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'TAB 2'        

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'CONFIGURE'
        size_hint_x: 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y":0.5}
        on_release: app.test_1(self)
        on_press: root.test_2(self)
''')


class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    # Class implementing content for a tab.
    pass


class MyProject(MDBoxLayout):
    # type-hints
    screen_manager: MDScreenManager
    _tabs: Tab

    # optional to build the icons in this widget
    icons = ["clock", "video-3d"]

    def test_2(self, my_button):
        print(f"Top Level(root) widget{my_button.text}\t{self}")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print(f"{self.screen_manager}\t{self._tabs}")

        for tab_name in self.icons:
            self._tabs.add_widget(Tab(icon=tab_name))


class MainApp(MDApp):

    icons = ["clock", "video-3d"]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._main = MyProject()

    def test_1(self, my_button):
        print(f"MainAPP {my_button.text}\t{self}")

    def build(self):

        return self._main

    def on_start(self):
        pass
        # this is one way, but another way is shown above
        # for tab_name in self.icons:
        #     self.root.ids._tabs.add_widget(Tab(icon=tab_name))

    def on_tab_switch(
            self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        """
        Called when switching tabs
        :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
        :param instance_tab: <__main__.Tab object>;
        :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
        :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
        """
        print(f"{instance_tabs} {instance_tab_label} {tab_text}")
        count_icon = instance_tab.icon

        if count_icon == self.icons[0]:
            self.root.screen_manager.current = 'screen1'
        elif count_icon == self.icons[1]:
            self.root.screen_manager.current = 'screen2'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Actually I solved my problem simply calling the screen manager from the *on_tab_switch* method with *self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "screen1"*, without using any type hints as you did. To your knowledge, can I call every widget defined in the layout with *self.root.ids.widgetName*?

Comment: I feel a bit confused about the two strategies you implemented: the one with all methods defined in the *MainApp(MDApp)* class and the one that defines another class, *MyProject*. What are the differences? Which one should be preferred? What about this design <https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Components-DropDownItem>? There is only a class in which some attributes of the layout components are defined in the *init* method.

Comment: Those are just two levels.  the App will have a top-level widget so the top 2 levels of the software are 1) App and 2) the root or top level widget.  Defining these explicitly is my choice; it is just a preference.